# Which command-line editor should be used in Windows 7 to modify settings

Tags: command-line, windows-7, command

Which command-line editor should be used in Windows 7 to modify settings such as the boot sequence, display order and time out values for multiple operating systems, or Emergency Management Services and boot debugging settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`bcdedit`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731662%28WS.10%29.aspx) I believe.

Scott Hanselman has a nice [walkthrough in the context of booting to a VHD](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LessVirtualMoreMachineWindows7AndTheMagicOfBootToVHD.aspx).